# How do I get my test to run with Maven Failsafe, not Surefire?

Tags: maven

Reading the [Failsafe plugin documentation](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/index.html), it talks about the integration-test phase but not how any given JUnit test would be counted as integration-test rather than normal (unit) test. Googling around, it seems like both surefire and failsafe will run, so it's not that failsafe is taking over and running all tests. So how do I make sure failsafe runs a given test?

Answer (score 1):

There's a separate documentation page on this: [Inclusions and Exclusions of Tests](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html)

Basically the main convention that people use seems to be adding IT as a suffix to the test case name. The pattern is configurable in the plugin as a regex, and specific test cases can be added or excluded as well.